# excel VBA importing multiple worksheets is slow

Tags: excel, vba, import

I use the following code to import multiple worksheets from another workbook and do some processing. the Importing time is too long. can any one suggest a more efficient way to import? Should I be looking in to more information in the source files for copy?

```
Sub SKR_Import()
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim filechosen As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    Dim i As Long
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fd.Title = "Select Excel workbooks to import all sheets"
    filechosen = fd.Show
    If filechosen = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))
            For Each Sht In wb2.Sheets
                Sht.Activate
                ActiveSheet.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
            Next Sht
            wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next i
    End If
    wb1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:
    msgBox Error, vbCritical, "Error"
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it necessary to `Sht.Activate`?  Can you not just `Sht.Copy`?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your time. Sht.Activate is not necessary i hope, I used Sht.copy directly... Still no effect on the timing... any guesses?

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity including best-practices. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: Sure Ralph, I will give a try. I am not a professional, just starting to use VBA... Stack Overflow is a great help though!

Comment: I found the solution. The secret was in the source file worksheets. They were protected and had lot of references to other worksheets & workbooks. I used a simple modification in copy - paste special in the origin sheet, and copy the sheet to destination workbook. While closing the source book, save changes to be provided false. this works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping on the sheets of `wb2`, you can try to copy them at once using the copy method of `sheets` (with an `s`):

```
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))
        ' For Each Sht In wb2.Sheets
        '     Sht.Activate
        '     ActiveSheet.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
        ' Next Sht
        wb2.Sheets.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
        wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

This will also get rid of the `Activate` statement, which wasn't necessary but only wasted some time.

I dont seem to find other ways to accelerate further your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion A.S.H. I tried with your suggestion:    wb2.Sheets.Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count). Sure its a better way, but the time taken is still too long. Not sure why. Any other guess in the source sheet?